# PHP Echo Refresh

Tags: php, html, submit, refresh

So I am using php to input and output from mysql database. 
When I use form to insert, after submit it echo's inserted. I want to ask How can I refresh the page when I press submit rather than showing a new page with 'Inserted'

Sorry I'm very new to this.

Here is my php code

```
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_username = "root";
$db_pass = "";
$db_name = "test_database";

$conn = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_pass) or die("Could not connect to mysql!");
mysql_select_db($db_name, $conn) or die("No Database");

$value = $_POST['input1'];
$value2 = $_POST['input2'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO users (username,pid) VALUES ('" . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "','" . mysql_real_escape_string($value2) . "')";
$q = mysql_query($sql);
if ($q) {
    echo "Inserted!";
} else {
    echo "Not inserted";
}

mysql_close();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$q=mysql_query($sql);
mysql_close();
```

That's all. You don't need the if statement.
or if it's another page you should redirect the user.

```
header('Location: something.php');
```

Comment: WHen I used that it just shows a blank page. How am I suppose to refresh my currect page with that? btw Your help was greatly appreciated. Im a student. very new

Comment: can you show the full code? is your form in the same page where the php code?

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
$q=mysql_query($sql);
if($q){
 header("Location: $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']");
}
else
{
  // do something else     
}
```

`header("Location: url")` is used to redirect to a given url,

`$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` is the current page.

So here we are actually refreshing the page.

You can also use it like this :

`header("Location: form_page.php")` to redirect to the form page

Answer (score 0):

Move the 'insert to DB' part of the code to this same page.

Add this to check for posted data

```
if( isset($_POST['fromPerson']) ){
//Add data to DB code here.
}
```

Then change your form to post to itself by amending the `action="AddToDatabase.php"` to post to the URL your currently in.

Answer (score 0):

Just be careful when using header() in PHP, you MUST NOT send any data before using it (any html, or simply an echo 'thing').